# C++ array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays

```
     int arr[] = {12, 34, 54, 2, 3}, i;
```

Happened to see an array declared this way, source here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shellsort/
What does the `,i`part mean? It doesn't seem to do anything yet compiles.

Comment: It means another `int` variable named `i` is declared here. `int a,b;, same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same as doing

```
int arr[] = {12, 34, 54, 2, 3};
int i;
```

You can declare and initialize more than one variable in a line, using `,`. In this case `arr` is initialized with `12, 34, 54, 2, 3` and `i` is just declared, but not initialized.

Comment: Like @avanti said in his answer, there is no right/wrong reason for declaring variables in one line. I tend to declare variables that relate to each other in one line. Other times I declared them in separate lines.

Answer (score 3):

This is just initialization syntax. It's equivalent in structure to:

```
int a = 0, i;
```

except that `arr` is the first variable declared, and it's given an initial value. `i` is the other variable declared, and it is not given an initial value.

Answer (score 1):

A declaration statement can declare multiple variables with the same type, separated by comma. So this is just declaring two variables, `arr`, and `i`. It's equivalent to:

```
int arr[] = {12, 34, 54, 2, 3};
int i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it just looks like they are declaring variables.

I.E

```
int i, j;
```

is basically the same as

```
int i;

int j;
```

It seems to be mostly personal choice for either method.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

> The i part is a integer variable. Its same as declareing as separate
>   follows where arr is initialised with 5 items and i is not initialised:

```
int arr[] = {12, 34, 54, 2, 3};
int i;
```

> For more illustration if you compile the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {12, 34, 54, 2, 3}, i = 5;
    cout<<"Print Arr[4] = "<<arr[4]<<"\nPrint i = "<<i;

    return 0;
}
```

> Then it will print:

```
Print Arr[4] = 3                                                                                                                      
Print i = 5
```

> From the above code you can understand that the arr and i are separate
>   variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as:

```
int arr[] = {12, 34, 54, 2, 3};
int i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int arr[] = {12, 34, 54, 2, 3}, i;
```

In this case it will give *warning C4101: 'i' : unreferenced local variable*. If you want to declare and initialize more than one variable in a line using ',' you have to follow same patter for compiler understanding.

for example,

```
int a = 2,b ; //  warning C4101: 'b' : unreferenced local variable.
```

**solution:1**

```
int arr[] = {12, 34, 54, 2, 3}, i(0); // you may write i = 0;
```

If you initialize value than initialize for all variables of that line.

**solution:2**

```
int arr[] = {12, 34, 54, 2, 3};
int i;
```

And i recommend to you follow this rule for all datatype.